# Open file explorer window via UXP Plugin in Photoshop

Tags: javascript, photoshop

In extendScript to open the file explorer in a specific directory is possible with:

```
Folder("~/Desktop/scanner").execute();
```

Is there any possibility to do this with UXP code or javasxript
If anyone knows any commands, please share.
Thanks.

Comment: For JavaScript to interact with anything external (like file explorer) it needs to have suitable APIs provided by the host environment and you haven't said what host environment you are using. I've never heard of *UXP code* but a quick Google suggests it is used for writing Photoshop plugins (and I know you can write them using JS too). Are you asking about doing this as JavaScript running in Photoshop (as opposed to JavaScript running in a `<script>`, browser extension, Node.js, WSH, or anything else)? Please edit the question to clarify and apply suitable tags (such as [tag:photoshop]!)